# Putting two asy images next to each other

Tags: asymptote

How do you put two asy images next to each other? Do you use wrap-fig?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(0.98cm);
draw(Label("x",Relative(0.98)),(-5,0)--(5,0),Arrows);
draw(Label("y",Relative(0.98),align=LeftSide),(0,-5)--(0,5),Arrows);
real margin=.1;
for (int a : new int[]{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}){
draw((a,0)-(0,margin)--(a,0)+(0,margin));
draw((0,a)-(margin,0)--(0,a)+(margin,0));
}
draw((-3,4)--(1,-4)--(5,4));

\end{asy}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(0.98cm);
draw(Label("x",Relative(0.98)),(-5,0)--(5,0),Arrows);
draw(Label("y",Relative(0.98),align=LeftSide),(0,-5)--(0,5),Arrows);
real margin=.1;
for (int a : new int[]{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}){
draw((a,0)-(0,margin)--(a,0)+(0,margin));
draw((0,a)-(margin,0)--(0,a)+(margin,0));
}
draw((-1,4)--(1,-4)--(3,4));

\end{asy}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Have you tried multicols ?

Comment: Simpler question: Have you tried putting them in the same `center` environment?

Comment: I do not know what those our, unfortunately. I am relatively knew to Overleaf and TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Subcaption is your friend.

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Make them smaller to fit next to each other.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{asy}[width=\textwidth]
    unitsize(0.98cm);
    draw(Label("x",Relative(0.98)),(-5,0)--(5,0),Arrows);
    draw(Label("y",Relative(0.98),align=LeftSide),(0,-5)--(0,5),Arrows);
    real margin=.1;
    for (int a : new int[]{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}){
    draw((a,0)-(0,margin)--(a,0)+(0,margin));
    draw((0,a)-(margin,0)--(0,a)+(margin,0));
    }
    draw((-3,4)--(1,-4)--(5,4));

    \end{asy}
    \caption{Figure a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{asy}[width=\textwidth]
    unitsize(0.98cm);
    draw(Label("x",Relative(0.98)),(-5,0)--(5,0),Arrows);
    draw(Label("y",Relative(0.98),align=LeftSide),(0,-5)--(0,5),Arrows);
    real margin=.1;
    for (int a : new int[]{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}){
    draw((a,0)-(0,margin)--(a,0)+(0,margin));
    draw((0,a)-(margin,0)--(0,a)+(margin,0));
    }
    draw((-1,4)--(1,-4)--(3,4));

    \end{asy}
    \caption{Figure b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```